# Promise and callback function in ajax, when does success take place ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Right now I have a code like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: apiUrl + valueToCheck,
            data: {
                format: 'json'
            },
            error: function () {
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                checkAgainstDBHelperWH(data, valueToCheck);
            },
            type: 'GET'
        });
```

If I am not mistaken, `checkAgainstDBHelperWH` is known as a callback function. The function executes once the servers sends back response for this particular HTTP /ajax request.

I want to try writing something like the one below, but I don't know what are the effects or is it even logical:

```
var request =  $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl + valueToCheck,
            data: {
                format: 'json'
            },
            error: function () {
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                checkAgainstDBHelperWH(data, valueToCheck);
            },
            type: 'GET'
        })

arrayOfPromises.push(request);


$.when.apply(null, arrayOfPromises).done(function () {

   //...some javascript here
 });
```

I want to understand if the `.done(function ()` is fired after the callback function `checkAgainstDBHelperWH` is completed? Or whatever I am trying to write above does not flow consistently with how ajax works?

Thanks!

Comment: It is NOT guaranteed that `done` will fire after the execution of `checkAgainstDBHelperWH` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it, your code only work if the function(in this case, 'checkAgainstDBHelperWH') doesn't call ajax.
If you want to wait finishing the inner ajax process, use then() and return inner ajax.

```
var ajaxs =
    $.get("xxx").then(function() {
        return $.get("yyy").done(function() {
        });
    });
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gchp4e2L/).

I'm not sure whether this way is general or not.